# Dojo - how to setup my JSON to populate another dijit.form.ComboBox wiht a preset of values

Tags: dojo

Here's an example:

I wanted to set up my JSON so it can have a list of countries corresponds to a list of states
(1) First I am setting up the storeData.  This is where I am having trouble.  How do I set up so that I can have a combo box of countries like the example below and another combobox that would have a pre-set of values based on selection of the country: for example:  if user selects 'United States' from the combo box, the 2nd combobox should have a list of 'Texas' and 'California'

```
<script type="text/javascript>
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
dojo.require("dijit.form.ComboBox");

var storeData = { identifier: 'name',
items: [
{ name: 'United States', state: ['Texas', 'California'] },
{ name: 'Canada', state: ['Alberta', 'Quebec'] }
]};

//
function init(){
 // Function to perform a lookup on the datastore on each change event of the combo  
    function getItemFromStore(){
    function lookUpState(item, request){
       var lNode = dijit.byId("country");

       if(!item){
           lNode.setDisplayedValue("");

       }else{
           //set up the pre-select list of states
           //logic goes here

       }
    }
 //invoke the lookup
    country.fetchItemByIdentity({identity: combo.getValue(), onItem: lookUpState});
    }
 // Link any change events in the combo to driving the fetchItemByIdentity lookup.
  dojo.connect(combo, "onChange", getItemFromStore);
  }
 // Set the init function to run when dojo loading and page parsing has completed.
 dojo.ready(init);
 </script>

 //HTML
 <div data-dojo-type="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" 
 data-dojo- props="data:storeData"     data-dojo-id="country"></div>
 <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboBox" data-dojo-props=
 "store:country, searchAttr:'name'" data-dojo-id="combo"></div>

<div class="formRow">
<label for="TestBox">State</label>
<input dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox" name="state" id="state" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See:
http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/form/FilteringSelect#codependent-filteringselect-combobox-widgets

look for the codependent state/city example.

Your date will need to be restructured to the format in the example in the link above